# How to do a multi-user process, using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do a multi-user process, currently it works perfectly, the problem I have now is that I need to do a multi-user process ...

I have an online invoice system that offers an available invoice number, the problem is that if two or more users enter at the same time, how can I make sure that different invoice numbers are saved?

In my model model `Cotizacion.php`

```
class Cotizacion extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cotizaciones';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public static function rules($cotizacion){
        $est=Cotizacion::where('n_cotiz',$cotizacion)->first();
        return $est;
    }
}
```

In my controller:

```
public function savecoti(Request $request){
    $posinum="00001$numerocotitiaguardar";
    $p=1;

    do{     
        $regla=Cotizacion::rules($posinum);
        if($regla){
            $limpiarproximo=ltrim($numerocotitiaguardar,"0");
            $limpiarproximo = $limpiarproximo +1;
            $valorproximo = str_pad($limpiarproximo, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $posinum="00001$valorproximo";
            $esta=1;
        }else{
            $esta=0;
            $limpiarproximo=ltrim($valorproximo,"0");
            $valorproximo = str_pad($limpiarproximo, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $numerocotities ="$sucursaltalonario$numerocotitiaguardar";
            $buscarencryp = new VProximo($valorproximo);  
            $encriptacion=  $buscarencryp->vervalor();
            $proximonumero = implode($encriptacion);
            $cotizacionsave->n_cotiz        = $numerocotities;
        }  
    }while ($esta==1);

    $cotizacionsave->save();
    $idcoti = $cotizacionsave->id;
}
```

As I say it works well but I have the problem if there are several users at the same time, what do I have to do or study to ensure that I do not save the same number?

Comment: Leave it to the database and it's [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Also, please never ever use any language but English in source code.

Comment: I apologize for my code is not in English

Comment: @jpmg You can, of course, use whatever language you want in your source code :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is typically what you would leave to the database. There is some possible approaches. Such as the auto increment of the database mentioned above. This is a guaranteed unique id.
If you want to use a specific column for this you should add a unique constraint to the column.

Secondly to ensure every thing goes well (avoid toctou race condition) you should use a database transaction which can be done easily from Laravel. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions in transactions. And https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use if you are interested in the details of TOCTOU.

As a small tip if your code would have been in English you would attract more helpers and avoid down votes.

Comment: I apologize for my code is not in English, ok thank you very much I will read what you say.